# Can QAOA solve a constraint optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, qaoa

Can QAOA solve a **constraint** binary optimization problem? QAOA is short for Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm. I read the information https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/qaoa.html.

But I'm not sure whether it can solve a **constraint** binary optimization problem.

Answer (score 3):

It can actually and this is done by adding penalties to include the constraints in the cost function. See [this article on formulations of different problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5843).

There also exist an adaptation for constrained problems. See [this articla on the Quantum Alternating Operator Ansatz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03489).

Comment: Thanks. I will read the two papers you recommend. It will take me time to finish reading it as I just begin quantum computing. Can you give me a Qiskit code to solve a constrained binary optimization with QAOA. Many thanks.

Comment: I could not find any for Qiskit in their githubs. Only this notebook shows the TSP formulation you could use to run QAOA on (for cost hamiltonian): https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/optimization/6_examples_max_cut_and_tsp.ipynb . Maybe worth for yourself to try QAOA on?

Comment: Yes, QAOA can solve a constraint mix integer programming.